# Как лучше организовать базу данных?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, оптимизация

Есть два варианта для организации структуры базы данных. 
Первый вариант создать одну таблицу с 4 колонками (Ид, тип, ключ, значение).
Второй вариант для каждого типа создать собственную таблицу, где в качестве ключа будет выступать колонка таблицы.

Проблема в том, что в первом варианте записей в таблице может быть за 100 000 (хотя он более гибкий), но во-втором случае около 100 таблиц(хотя это не проблема, таблицу генерируются автоматически)

Более наглядная схема:

**1 Вариант:**

```
ID  |  type  |  key |  value   
1     'cat1'  'key1'   'value1'
1     'cat1'  'key2'   'value2' 
1     'cat1'  'key3'   'value3' 
2     'cat1'  'key1'   'value4'
2     'cat1'  'key2'   'value5' 
2     'cat1'  'key3'   'value6' 
3     'cat2'  'keyn'   'valuen'
....
```

**2 Вариант**

```
Таблица cat1
id  |   key1  |  key2  | key3
 1     value1 | value2 | value3
 2     value3 | value4 | value5
```

Вопрос какой вариант оптимальнее. Есть ли глобальные отличия в производительности? Что можно применить, чтобы повысить производительность? Буду рад любому совету

Comment: 100тыс записей в таблице не должны быть проблемой, а вот 100 полей и 100 внешних таблиц для однотипных вещей вряд ли можно назвать здравым решением. При 100 полях у вас там вдобавок каждый раз 90 из них будут null иметь.небось.

Comment: Считается (не всегда и не всеми, но как правило), что клиентское приложение НЕ ДОЛЖНО не то что исполнять - даже иметь прав на выполнение DDL. У Вас явно не случай-исключение. Так что только одна таблица.

Answer (score 2):

Не понимаю, в чем проблема?

**types**

```
id | type | value
1    cat1 | value1
2    cat2 | value2
```

**keys**

```
id | key  | value
1    key1 | value1
2    key2 | value2
```

**types_keys**

```
id | type_id | key_id | value
1    1       | 1      | value1
2    1       | 2      | value2
```

**animals**

```
id | value
1  | value1
2  | value2
```

**animals_types_keys**

```
id | animal_id | type_key_id
1    1         | 1
2    1         | 2
```

Вроде, этот вариант структуры бд позволяет динамично работать с вашими данными.

Хотя, можно и сделать вместо 2 таблиц **types_keys** и **animals_types_keys** одну таблицу **animals_types_keys**:

```
id | animal_id | type_id | key_id | value
1    1         | 1       | 1      | value1
2    1         | 1       | 2      | value2
```

Похоже, что это фактически ваша таблица, только приведена к нормальной форме.